Geometry Question with One Given Angle Bisector

In $\Delta PQR$, $\angle QPR = 110^{\text{o}}$. Suppose $A$ is a point
on $QR$ such that $\angle QPA= 70^{\text{o}}$ and $\angle APR=
 40^{\text{o}}$. $B$ is a point on $PQ$ such that $BR$ is an angle
bisector of $\angle PRQ$. Find $\angle ABR$.

I was lost in this question. I was thinking about angle bisector theorem, which gives us $\frac{PR}{RQ}=\frac{PB}{BQ}$, but it does not seem to provide us any useful hint on finding the angle. I also tried considering point $C$ on $QR$ such that $\angle CPA = 40^{\text{o}}$. It is getting me nowhere. Any help is appreciated. You can leave some useful hints and I would like to work out the solutions on my own. Thanks in advance.

If an illustrative image was embedded directly in the posted question, it would make the question easier to attack.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of
this article
and see also this article.

Are you sure that angle is unique?

@Dominique Checked on Geogebra, try dragging point C.

Hint: what is $B$ with respect to the triangle $PRA$?

Thank you @D S for the hint. It takes me to the answer very quickly.
Extend $RP$ to point $S$. Note that $\angle SPQ = 70^{\text{o}} = \angle QPA$.
Hence, $B$ is the ex-centre of $\Delta PAR$. It implies that $\angle BAQ = \angle BAP$.
Let $x = \angle ABR$, $y = \angle BRA = \angle BRP$ and $M$ be the point of intersection of $PA$ and $BR$.
By considering exterior angle of $\Delta BAR$, $\angle BAQ = \angle BAP = x + y$.
By considering exterior angle of $\Delta PMR$, $\angle PMB = 40^{\text{o}} + y$.
By considering exterior angle of $\Delta ABM$, we have $$x + (x+y) = 40^{\text{o}} + y$$
which implies that $x = 20^{\text{o}}$. Hence, $\angle ABR = 20^{\text{o}}$.
